# The length of the formula in Monadic second-order logic

Tags: parameterized-complexity, treewidth

The Courcelle's theorem as following:
[image]

Obviously, we need the length of the $\varphi$~(that is $||\varphi||$)~in Theorem. However, how to caculate the length of $\varphi$?

For example, $$\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{conn}(X)=\quad & \forall_{Y \subseteq V}\left[\left(\exists_{u \in X} u \in Y \wedge \exists_{v \in X} v \notin Y\right)\right.\\
&\left.\Rightarrow\left(\exists_{e \in E} \exists_{u \in X} \exists_{v \in X} \operatorname{inc}(u, e) \wedge \operatorname{inc}(v, e) \wedge u \in Y \wedge v \notin Y\right)\right] .
\end{aligned}$$,

$||\operatorname{conn}(X)||=?$, how to caculate it?

Comment: Within a constant factor, just count the length of the text you just wrote.

Comment: I don't see why it matters, given that Theorem 7.11 doesn't specify the function $f$.

Comment: If the length of formula $\varphi$ is not constant, then there is no FPT algorithm parameterized by treewidth.

Comment: How long is the quantifier? for example, $\exists v \in V$?